# Is there a way to register more fingerprints for TouchID on a MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-id

It seems strange to me I can only register 3 finger prints for TouchID on my new 2016 MacBook Pro.

Is there any way to get macOS to allow for more?

Note: I know with iPhones you could fool it by alternating fingers back and forth while registering them and may try that, but 3 just seem bizarrely limiting.

Preempting the person that asks why? I place my MacBook on a rain stand regularly to the left of my external monitor and it'd be easier to use my left had to reach the sensor...  coupled with the face that I occasionally do things (usually twisting copper wires) the chews up the finger prints on my index finger...  all together it'd be nice to register middle, index and thumb on BOTH hands.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One option it to alternate fingers back and forth while registering them. 
ie. place your right index one press, then right middle one press, then right index again for one press, etc... Do that the same when you get to the edges. You'll be able to unlock using either finger stored in a single memory location.

I currently use this, it does work, I've heard of people registering several finger prints to a single location on iOS. I'd rather register them discretely though, hence why I asked this question.

I suspect it's accuracy goes down as the number of finger prints goes up, but I haven't seen that with just two prints on one memory slot.

Comment: dude this just awesome solution, works like a charm

Comment: Briljant .. works like a charm lol